# CsvHelper.CsvRead returns nothing

Tags: c#, csvhelper

My first time using CSVHelper.

I have a simple CSV file like this:

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

When I try to read it using this code:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"e:\a.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    // Do any configuration to `CsvReader` before creating CsvDataReader.
    using (var dr = new CsvDataReader(csv))
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
    }
}
```

`csv` returns nothing:

```
{CsvHelper.CsvReader}
    ColumnCount: 0
    Configuration: {CsvConfiguration { AllowComments = False, BadDataFound = CsvHelper.BadDataFound, BufferSize = 4096, CacheFields = False, Comment = #, CountBytes = False, CultureInfo = , Delimiter = ,, DetectDelimiter = False, DetectDelimiterValues = System.String[], DetectColumnCountChanges = False, DynamicPropertySort = , Encoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding, Escape = ", ExceptionMessagesContainRawData = True, GetConstructor = CsvHelper.GetConstructor, GetDynamicPropertyName = CsvHelper.GetDynamicPropertyName, HasHeaderRecord = True, HeaderValidated = CsvHelper.HeaderValidated, IgnoreBlankLines = True, IgnoreReferences = False, IncludePrivateMembers = False, InjectionCharacters = System.Char[], InjectionEscapeCharacter =  , IsNewLineSet = False, LeaveOpen = False, LineBreakInQuotedFieldIsBadData = False, MemberTypes = Properties, MissingFieldFound = CsvHelper.MissingFieldFound, Mode = RFC4180, NewLine = 
, PrepareHeaderForMatch = CsvHelper.PrepareHeaderForMatch, ProcessFieldBufferSize = 1024, Quote = ", ReadingExceptionOccurred = CsvHelper.ReadingExceptionOccurred, ReferenceHeaderPrefix = , SanitizeForInjection = False, ShouldQuote = CsvHelper.ShouldQuote, ShouldSkipRecord = CsvHelper.ShouldSkipRecord, ShouldUseConstructorParameters = CsvHelper.ShouldUseConstructorParameters, TrimOptions = None, UseNewObjectForNullReferenceMembers = True, WhiteSpaceChars = System.Char[] }}
    Context: {CsvHelper.CsvContext}
    CurrentIndex: -1
    HeaderRecord: null
    Parser: {CsvHelper.CsvParser}
```

What is the problem? I cannot figure it out.

Comment: It worked fine for me.

Comment: See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i4YvF4). Testing locally I used your code as-is, save for changing the file location. Obviously I couldn't do that on DotNetFiddle, so I replaced it with `StringReader`. I also tested `\n` instead of `\r\n`. See [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BBFrTU).

Comment: @Llama weird, still does not work with me!

Comment: Does it work if you copy my example directly?

Comment: @Llama yes, but still not working !!! i restarted my computer and still the same

Comment: I have tried same above code and its working fine for me.

Comment: @Llama is there a way I can get the error provided by csvreader?

Comment: What version of CsvHelper are you using?  The fiddle from @Llama uses version 27, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/MOqTPV.

Comment: @dbc I use 27.0.2

Comment: I *think* the fiddle is using that one also.  Even though it says `27.0.0.0`, if I remove it and add 27.0.2 I get `27.0.0.0` shown.  My observation is that `Assembly.FullName` doesn't always show the minor version (it doesn't for Json.NET either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test the code below I think the problem is how to open the file with `StreamReader`

```
using (var streamReader = File.OpenText(path))
{
   using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
   {
       using (var dr = new CsvDataReader(csvReader))
       {
           var dt = new DataTable();
           dt.Load(dr);
       }
   }
}
```